# Difference between “+”, “-” and “^” operators in PHP?

Tags: php

Difference between “+”, “-” and **“^”** operators in PHP?

```
echo "<br>";
echo 200+233; //433
echo "<br>";
echo 200^233; //33
echo "<br>";
echo 233^20; //253
```

As you see sometimes **'^'** works as '-' and sometimes as '+'...

**What a rule?**

Comment: `^` is xor. `+` is addition and `-` is subtraction.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php vs http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: It would definitely be worth checking out and favoriting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: Simply doing a Google search for [php caret](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+caret) tells you exactly what it would do. I suggest you read documentation for the languages you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XOR operator. It's a binary operator that returns true if both inputs are not the same:

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

So it's looking at the two numbers you have input as binary numbers and comparing each bit and returning a new result:

```
200 in binary = 11001000
233 in binary = 11101001
result          00100001
```

That result as a decimal number is 33.